# how can i detect a space and replace the spaces found with a characer?

Tags: java

So what I'm trying to do is to detect the following,

1. The letter "x" (and "X") is replaced by "ks"
2. The spaces are replaced by the letter X
3. All letters are capitalised.
4. All other characters are ignored and all accented letters are
   replaced by their regular counterparts

this is what I have and I'm not sure what to do next.

```
public static String message(){
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a message in order to perform the opertation.");
String message = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
message = message.replaceAll(" ","X");
message = message.replaceAll("X","ks");

return message;
```

}

Comment: `String#replaceAll` would be a starting point

Comment: If i do that, how would I be able to later on refer to each index of the string?  lets say i have "Fish are birds without wings and birds are fish without fins" how would I be able to use each of those letters later on  if its a string rather than a char[] ?

Comment: `String#indexOf` might also help

Comment: can you plesae provide me an example of String index of ? what does it do ? like if i have "hello my friend" how can i refer to the string by index? is h[0]? and e[1] and so on..?

Comment: @newprogrammer RTFM https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-

Comment: I used replace all but it only changes one part , if i do "xman is cool" the out put is ksmanksiscool... i did replace all for 2 parts of the assignment... it gave me that output

Comment: Post your code, I don't know know what you're attempting to replace.

Comment: public static String message(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a message in order to perform the opertation.");
    String message = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    message = message.replaceAll(" ","X");
    message = message.replaceAll("X","ks");
  
    return message;
  }

Comment: I reposted the new code, i think it would be better to look at it formatted

Comment: You just need to swap the `String#replaceAll` calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to do the entire assignment for you, but you should use a `String` instead of a `char` array:

```
String message = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();

message = message.replaceAll(" ", "X");
```

Comment: but how would i be able to control each specific character within that string? because later on i will have to use each two letters grouped and move them for my assignment .. So charp[] is not a good idea ?

Comment: A `String` is immutable, so you'll have to store each `String#substring` in a variable depending on what your assignment it.  I really recommend reading the documentation or even looking up some YouTube videos if you're confused.

Comment: yes. [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class has all the methods you require to do the tasks you require.